# Weirdest Bluetooth behaviour ever - AsRock Fatal1ty ITX, Windows 10, Logitech K380

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, bluetooth, troubleshooting, amd-ryzen

I'm loosing my mind here so I hope someone has a solution to this nightmare.

I've recently built my first pc with Ryzen 2600x and AsRock X370 board (here is a detailed list of components: https://www.x-kom.pl/lista/idztlps8w).
I have Logitech bluetooth keyboard and a wireless mouse from the old setup (laptop) - both never failed me until now.

As soon as the first boot of the system I had problems with connecting the keyboard to the PC. The PC didn't see any bluetooth devices. I resolved it by connecting an additional wifi antenna (came with the board). Now it connects and pairs without a problem.

After a few days my current issue came up. 
The keybord stopps working from time to time. Although it is 'connected' in the Bluetooth and devices panel, the keys don't work. Sometimes it freezes on one key (presses it all the time). As you imagine it's very frustrating. Especially when I work in Photoshop or Illustrator and I REALLY need my keys and shortcuts.

The weirdest part is what usually helps (although temporarily). 
Sometimes going to `Windows Settings -> Devices` works. I just open this panel, it uploads the view of the bluetooth devices and suddenly the keys work.
The other thing that works is going to troubleshoot settings and running the bluetooth troubleshoot.
This is what I get from the [Troubleshoot report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9S1uq.png)

All this works only for a while - During 1 hour of work I have to do these steps probably every 5-10 minutes.

**What I've noticed:**

- the keyboard works fine without trouble on my old laptop and my phone
- I want to say it happens more while I'm using PS and ILLU, but maybe it just annoys me more.
- I have a little JBL speaker - I don't use it as much as the keyboard but the times I have - I didn't have any problems.
- From what I gather from the troublehoot report the PC somehow shuts the Bluetooth down but idk why - and then when I open the devices panel it kind of realises it should have it on and reconnects. - but this is not consistent

**What I've done already:**

- changed the batteries
- Removed and paired the device numerous times
- run the troubleshooter
- reinstalled the device from the device manager
- reinstalled the drivers
- updated the drivers for basically everything first fith generic versions, then manually with drivers from manufacturers websites and then with Driver Booster
- run `sfc /scannow`
- installed dedicated software for the devices (mobo and keybord)
- `Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Devices and printers -> Properties of the Keyboard -> check that the box Drivers for keyboard, mouce etc; (HID). is ticked`
- `services.msc -> Bluetooth Support Service -> Startup type -> automatic`
- cleaned the registry
- rebooted after every step

Please help. I've tried every solution that I'd found and nothing works. I was so happy about buying this PC and now I just want to throw it out the window.

Comment: "cleaned the registry" how did you do that?

Comment: @Moab Thank you for the comment. I've used CCleaner. Should I do this some other way?

//It happened twice during writing this comment. </3

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, so for the sake of future generation: I've found a recurring warning in the Windows event log called HidTBH, googled it and applied solution from this post:
http://www.evilbox.ro/windows/solve-bluetooth-mouse-disconnecting-under-windows/
It works now :)
Triumph!